# PHP calculation different with SQL & Excel result

Tags: php, sql, excel

I tried to calculate using SQL and found out that the result was different with the excel one,

My table setting :

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| qty_final          | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price_final_usd    | decimal(20,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My table content:

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| qty_final | price_final_usd |
+-----------+-----------------+
|         1 |           53.22 |
|         2 |          125.05 |
|         3 |           23.15 |
|         4 |          114.79 |
|         4 |          395.06 |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

my sql query :

```
UPDATE $table SET amount_final = round((qty_final * price_final_usd),2)
```

my php code :

```
$amount_final = round($qty_final * $price_final_usd, 2);
```

my excel formula :

```
=ROUND(qty_final * price_final_usd,2)
```

Here's the result comparison

[image: calculation result]

Can someone tell me how to correct the PHP code ?
I want exactly the same result between them

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://3v4l.org/E9J32

Comment: You may want to echo `$price_final_usd` in your PHP right before the snippet you posted to check if it matches what you have stored in your table. It seems the most likely thing to be wrong here.

Comment: Thanks @Sellyme, it was wrong $price_final_usd, i had to add the round on it too, now it solved